# try catch in Codeceptjs with playwright

Tags: javascript, try-catch, codeceptjs

This code, i am running in my page class

```
I.fillField ("input[@class='test']", "name");
}
catch(error){
console.log("Error is occured");
I.refreshPage();
}
```

If script is unable to fill the text in textbox. instead of failing the case,.. it go to catch section.. refresh the page

This code is working .. but problem it after execution of catch block .. test got failed instead of continue the execution

I have also tried some solutions present on some forms like mentioned below. but facing same issue

```
I.fillField ("input[@class='test']", "name").catch((error)=>{
      I.say("Error is occured");
      I.say(error);
      I.refreshPage();
    });
```

Can anyone help me to implement try catch block in codeceptjs

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `tryto` for this. https://codecept.io/plugins/#tryto

```js
const hasBeenFilled = await tryTo(() => I.fillField ("input[@class='test']", "name"));

if (!hasBeenFilled) {
  I.refreshPage();
}
```

Make sure you have in `codecept.conf.js` plugin turn to true:

```
plugins: {
  tryTo: {
    enabled: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the perfect answer.